# I cannot invoke my html views in embedded Tomcat / Intellij - Springboot with Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, http-status-code-404

I was working in a projet in intellij using: Spring-boot, maven and thymeleaf. At first I was running it as a Java application and it worked perfectly, but when I wanted to deploy it in a local Tomcat server or embedded Tomcat it can't resolve my html pages. I get the 404 not found message each time.

I tried to maven deploy in the tomcat manager, and them in the embedded tomcat in intellij and always the same problem. 
I tried created a thymeleaf configuration file and always the same problem.

This is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>

        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.EPS</groupId>
    <artifactId>EPS</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>EPS</name>
    <description>project EPS Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <start-class>com.programmer.gate.EpsApplication</start-class>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>


</project>
```

And this is my ThymeleafConfiguration.java

```
package com.EPS.EPS.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.SpringTemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class ThymeleafConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(thymeleafTemplateResolver());
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver thymeleafTemplateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver
                = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/classes/templates");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        return templateResolver;
    }
}
```

This is my indexController.jave

```
package com.EPS.EPS.web.controller;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/templates")
public class IndexController {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IndexController.class);

    /*@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
    @GetMapping(value = "/")
    public String index() {
        return "ajax";
    }*/

    //Authentification
    @GetMapping(value = "/login")
    public String login() {
        logger.info("worked!!");
        return "login/login.html";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/")
    public RedirectView RedirectLogin() {
        return new RedirectView("/login");
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/login/error")
    public String loginerror() {
        return "login/errorlogin";
    }

    //Gestion des utilisateurs et des roles
    //utilisateurs
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('Gestion_utilisateurs')")
    @GetMapping(value = "/gestion_utilisateurs")
    public String gestion_utilisateur() {
        return "gestion_utilisateurs/gestion_utilisateurs";
    }

    .....

}
```

And this is my main Java class EpsApplication.java

```
package com.EPS.EPS;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class EpsApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer  {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(EpsApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(EpsApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Here is my project tree:
[image]

This is what I get
[image]

Comment: Since your controller has @RequestMapping("/templates"), every method mappings map /templates/whatever. As seen in the url you invoked, there's no /templates, hence the 404. Also when you invoke the url, do so with th syntax (@{...})

Comment: I added the templete to link, but it gives me the html page, still it doesn't work correctly, once I write my username and password  they give me an 405 error (Method not allowed) and nothing in the server output on intellij?

Comment: the error you are getting is because of wrong configuration of Spring security.

Comment: @SujayMohan it worked now. Thanks.